Enable 'Validate existing pooled connection' on Websphere using jython script
I'm trying to enable Validate existing pooled connection for datasource using a jython script but nothing is applied. However, it worked for validateNewConnection attribute.
I'm using:
#Define validateNewConnection
      name_validateNewConnection = ['name', 'validateNewConnection']
      value_validateNewConnection = ['value', 'true']
      validateNewConnectionAttrs = [name_validateNewConnection, value_validateNewConnection]

      #Define validateExistingPooledConnection
      name_validateExistingPooledConnection = ['name', 'validateExistingPooledConnection']
      value_validateExistingPooledConnection = ['value', 'true']
      validateExistingPooledConnectionAttrs = [name_validateExistingPooledConnection, value_validateExistingPooledConnection]

      #Define validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval
      name_validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval = ['name', 'validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval']
      value_validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval = ['value', '3']
      validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryIntervalAttrs = [name_validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval, value_validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval]

AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', propSetvol, validateExistingPooledConnectionAttrs)
      AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', propSetvol, validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryIntervalAttrs)
      AdminConfig.save()

enter image description here
validateExistingPooledConnection & validateExistingPooledConnectionRetryInterval are only added in custom properties.
Tried with testConnection and preTestConnections attribute names but without success.
I'm expecting to enable 'Validate existing pooled connection' and change the retry interval.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Achieved it by changing [testConnection "true"] [testConnectionInterval "3"]] attributes in connection pool.
ds = AdminConfig.getid(ServerScope + '/JDBCProvider:OracleJDBC/DataSource:DS_DB/')
conpool=AdminConfig.showAttribute(ds, 'connectionPool')
AdminConfig.modify(conpool, '[[testConnection "true"] [testConnectionInterval "3"]]')

